# Example of a set where $Int(\overline{A}) = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to picture in my mind what a *nowhere dense* set might look like. I know the definition, but I'm specifically looking for an example or two to use for mental images. For example, I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but I am a little lost on looking for sets where $Int(\overline{A}) = \emptyset$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You already mentioned an example: $\Bbb Z$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$ with empty interior, so it satisfies your condition. Alternatively, the Cantor set is a closed set with empty interior. M

Comment: Can you comment on why $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ has an empty interior? I do not see it immediately.

Comment: Any *closed* countable set as empty interior, @clocktower: if a set contains an open interval, it must be uncountable (since open intervals are uncountable). Note that $\Bbb Z$ is closed in the usual topology, so it is its own closure.